# android: How to place a view with an ActionBar in an ExpandableList ChildView

Tags: android, android-widget

I understand ActionBar only works within an Activity, like it's not a View (shame). 
My problem is: I want a View with an ActionBar to pop up as the ChildView of an ExpandableList.
I suppose a TabbedView would do but probably presents the same obstacle, which ends up as
How to inflate an Activity as a ExpandableListchild view and pluck the Tab widget?
Is there a way?
Could I create a Tabbed View without the encumberence of a TabActivity? 
Fragments any use? Sherlock might know?